# Алгоритм проверки столкновения двух движущихся окружностей

Tags: коллизии

Нужен оптимальный алгоритм определения столкновения двух движущихся окружностей. 
Окружности задаются координатами центров и радиусами. Движение задается углом и длинной вектора. При этом считается что обе окружности переместятся из начальной точки в конечную за одно и то-же время, т.е. скорости их движения зависят от длинны вектора. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Алгоритм "в лоб" который я сейчас использую:

- Определяю количество итераций пути из расчета N = MAX(size1/r1, size2/r2) * 2
- Разбиваю движение каждой окружности на N частей
- В цикле от 0 до N вычисляю положение каждой окружности и проверяю пересечение.

Алгоритм хорош всем кроме одного - это производительность.
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей? Наверняка есть математическое описание этой модели.

Comment: Координаты центров есть функция времени. Расстояние между ними - соответственно тоже. Очевидно, что функция расстояния от времени имеет минимум (оба предела - бесконечность). Осталось его найти. Проще всего продифференцировать аналитически, и найти корень полученного уравнения численно. После чего посчитать расстояние в минимуме и сравнить с суммой радиусов. Меньше? значит, столкнутся...

Comment: Если нужно не только проверить, а ещё найти момент столкновения, то лучше тоже самое уравнение движения (D=f(t)) просто решить для D=R^2+r^2 (оно будет квадратным). Если одно решение, значит коснуться, если два — столкнутся, если нет — значит нет.

Comment: "...Движение задается углом и длинной вектора..." - правильно,ли я понимаю, что скорость постоянна по модулю и направлению?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Представим ваши углы и длины по другому, а именно в координаты начальных и конечных точек. Окружности будут двигаться так:

```
(x11; y11) -> (x12; y12)
(x21; y21) -> (x22; y22)
```

Введем параметр `t` (время), который изменяется от `0` до `1`. При `t=0` окружности находятся в исходных точках, при `t=1` - в конечных. Тогда координаты центров окружностей во время движения будут:

```
x1 = x11 + (x12 - x11) * t
y1 = y11 + (y12 - y11) * t

x2 = x21 + (x22 - x21) * t
y2 = y21 + (y22 - y21) * t
```

В момент соприкосновения расстояние между центрами окружностей равно сумме радиусов. Получаем:

```
(r1 + r2)^2 = (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2
```

Если подставить координаты точек в уравнение соприкосновения, получим огромное квадратное уравнение относительно `t`. Его коэффициенты такие:

```
a = x11 * x11 + x12 * x12 + y11 * y11 + y12 * y12 + x21 * x21 + x22 * x22 + y21 * y21 + y22 * y22
    + 2 * (- x11 * x12 - x21 * x22 - y11 * y12 - y21 * y22 - x11 * x21 - y11 * y21 + x11 * x22 + y11 * y22 + x12 * x21 + y12 * y21 - x12 * x22 - y12 * y22);
b = 2 * (
    - x11 * x11 - x21 * x21 - y11 * y11 - y21 * y21 +
    x11 * x12 + y11 * y12 + x21 * x22 + y21 * y22 - x11 * x22 - y11 * y22 - x12 * x21 - y12 * y21 + 2 * x11 * x21 + 2 * y11 * y21)
c = x11 * x11 - 2 * x11 * x21 + x21 * x21 + y11 * y11 - 2 * y11 * y21 + y21 * y21 - (r1 + r2) * (r1 + r2);
```

Как и любое квадратное уравнение, оно может иметь 0 решений (окружности не пересекаются), бесконечность решений (окружности скользят по параллельных отрезках), 2 решения (окружности соприкасаются, пересекаются, и расходятся), 1 решение (окружности касаются только один раз).

Плюс к этому нужно проверить, входит ли `t` в промежуток `0..1`.

Пример:

```
(-5; -10) -> (3; 10)   [r1 = 1]
(-10; -1) -> (10; -10) [r2 = 1]
```

Решения:

```
t1 = 0.274411137729595
t2 = 0.377365512016598
```

Координаты окружностей в момент пересечения:

```
(-2.805; -4.512)
(-4.512; -3.470)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не успел, опередили секунд на 5 :) ставлю плюс

Comment: всё хорошо, только вот формулы бы записать нормально через промежуточные члены, а не вместо этого багогенератора...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это как через промежуточные члены? Формулы я скопировал с рабочей тестовой программки, не должно быть багов

Comment: @Zergatul добавил ответом, в комментарий не умещу... в текущем виде, проблема в том, что это не читаемо и не проверяемо, а опечатка в одном символе чревата часом перепроверки.

Comment: @Fat-Zer а зачем перепечатывать, если можно скопировать? :)

Answer (score 0):

Упрощённая запись формул:

Заданы два тела

- A (Xa;Ya; скорость Va[x,y], радиус ra)
- B (Xb;Yb; скорость Vb[x,y], радиус rb):

Тогда:

```
dVx = Vax - Vbx
dVy = Vay - Vby

dx = Xa - Xb
dy = Ya - Yb

R = ra + rb

# Коэффициенты уравнения:

a = dVx^2 + dVy^2
b = 2*(dx*dVx + dy*dVy)
c = dx^2 + dy^2 - R^2
```

ЗЫ: выводил на коленке, так что за абсолютную достоверность не ручаюсь.